# Cannot install grub due to "cannot stat `aufs'" error

Tags: 11.04, grub2

I have installed these OS in the order give below:

```
Windows7  
Ubuntu 11.04  
Fedora 15
```

Before installation of Fedora 15 all was working fine. Ubuntu grub shows Windows and Ubuntu in the list. When Fedora 15 is installed Ubuntu's grub was lost. I am trying to restore Ubuntu grub from Ubuntu live usb drive.So that the fedora will chainload Ubuntu grub.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/media/926afad4-4c2a-4f0f-8b2c->801e07c9ec26/boot /dev/sda2  
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot stat `aufs'.
```

Please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might be here:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/media/926afad4-4c2a-4f0f-8b2c-801e07c9ec26/boot **/dev/sda2**
```

The `/dev/sda2`, which is the second partition (the 2) on your first hard drive (the a), should just be `/dev/sda`, which refers to just to the hard drive as a whole.

When the computer starts, the BIOS will determine which device to boot from (based on your boot order settings). Should it be your first hard drive (`/dev/sda`), then the computer will look for a bootloader installed at the very beginning of the Master Boot Record (MBR), the first sector of the HDD. You're trying to install grub probably somewhere deep in the hard drive.

```
|--|---------------------------------------|--------------------------------|
^  ^                                       ^
|  |__ Start of 1st partition /dev/sda1    |__Start of 2nd partition /dev/sda2
|                                             where you're trying to install 
|                                             grub
|
|__Start of hard drive, the MBR starts here, the bootloader should live in 
   here, the partition tables as well, all before the first partition.
```

**TL;DR** change `/dev/sda2` to `/dev/sda`

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

1

- Unmount the drive before attempting to install grub.

2

- Use `sudo fdisk -l` to find your drive.
- Then use `sudo grub-install /dev/<partitionhere>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to: Just download and install "Boot repair" http://mygeekopinions.blogspot.com/2011/06/install-boot-repair-in-ubuntu-1104.html . Just like that. I did it and it works.